# Using MAVEN for Staging and Production Builds

Tags: android, maven

In my android project i am using MAVEN for staging and production builds. The only difference between these two is that i use different URL for consuming the rest services. So i am looking for a way in which i can use MAVEN to make both builds. I am thinking of moving the rest URL portion of my code to a separate java jar and declare this jar as a dependency in my project.

So i will have two jar. One that will point my application to production and one that will point my application to a staging URL. Now i would need to include only one of these based on a parameter when i say something like `mvn clean install -staging or mvn clean isntall -production`

How can i achieve this. Any help in this will be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [How to Create Two JARs from One Project (…and why you shouldn't)](http://blog.sonatype.com/people/2010/01/how-to-create-two-jars-from-one-project-and-why-you-shouldnt/).

Comment: What i am looking for is something that allows me include one of two possible dependencies in my project ? So something that allows me to say if this is a staging build include this dependency else if its a production build include this dependency.

Comment: If you follow this approach you will deploy artifacts to your repository where you can not distinguish if it was build for staging or production. IMHO you should build two different artifacts (maybe with staging/production identifier in the groupId).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Maven Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).  Profiles, when active, modify specific areas of your pom - so you could include or exclude a dependency by modifying the `<dependencies>` element, for example.  You can specify which profile to use at build time easily on the command line like this:

```
mvn package -Pstaging
```

So for example, if you wanted to use you could add some profiles to your pom like this:

```
<project>
  ...
  <profiles>

    <profile>
      <name>staging</name>
      <properties>
        <rest.url>http://staging.rest/url</rest.url>
      </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <name>production</name>
      <properties>
        <rest.url>http://production.rest/url</rest.url>
      </properties>
    </profile>

  <profiles>
</project>
```

Then when you're ready to go, you can run your build using the appropriate profile:

```
mvn clean install -Pstaging
```

The maven property will be set by the profile.  You can use this property elsewhere in your pom, for example you might filter a properties file to include the `rest.url` value, and have your application read it at runtime.  Have a look at the [Maven Resources Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html), which allows you to define resources that will be used by the application, and filter them based on properties in your pom.

Comment: Can you show me an example or point me to a pom where this is been used.

Comment: As I understood @user1730789 wants to "package" different dependencies into his app what of course is possible with profiles but IMHO not recommended. Once the app is deployed in the repository you will not be able to see what is inside unless you really unpack it and look inside. So better build dedicated artifacts/apps for each environment.

Comment: I agree you don't want to deploy artifacts with environment-specific config into your Maven repo.  To avoid that, you can build the artifact without the config, and add it as a dependency to another pom-type project which can filter it at build time.  The general approach would be to build and deploy library artifacts to your maven repo, and to assemble a complete application using them for deployment to the target environment.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend to use profiles to change the content of your build artifact. Once your artifact is build and deployed to your repository you are not able to distinguish if it was build for your staging or production environment (unless you look inside the artifact).

So as a simple solution I would make a second `pom.xml` for staging (e.g. `pom-staging.xml`) and give the artifact dedicated Maven coordinates like,

```
<groupId>foo.bar.staging</groupId>
<artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
```

You can than change everything that is different for the staging environment in this pom (e.g. dependencies) and build a dedicated statging application with

```
mvn -f pom-staging.xml install
```

Comment: This is a good point, in your case it may just be better to have a properties file on each environment which specifies the environment-specific config for you.

Comment: @Conan That would probably be the best solution but here an Android project is handled and I think you can not provide a property file an each phone. You could make the URL configurable by a App setting but I think in normal cases this should be hidden for the user.

Comment: Yep, +1 for not exposing this sort of config to the user.  In that case, filtering of resources wants to happen when assembling the deployment artifact aimed at the target environment, e.g. an app store.  You're bang on that you don't want this kind of config in your maven repo - although you can leave tokens in the repository and filter them on the way out, which works ok.